# Trig Identity in Problem

Tags: trigonometry

I'm self-studying Riley's Math Methods book and going through an early exercise and I can't for the life of me see how they've used the trig identities mentioned to rewrite the equation in the very first line of the solution. Any chance anyone here can explicitly walk me through it?

> > Find all the solutions of $$\sin\theta + \sin4\theta = \sin2\theta + \sin3\theta$$ that lie in the range $-\pi < \theta\le\pi$. What is the multiplicity of the solution $\theta = 0$?
>
> Using $$\begin{align}\sin(A + B) &= \sin A\cos B + \cos A\sin B,\quad\text{and} \\ \cos A - \cos B &= -2\sin\left(\frac{A + B}2\right)\sin\left(\frac{A - B}2\right),\end{align}$$ and recalling that $\cos\left(-\phi\right) = \cos\left(\phi\right)$, the equation can be written successively as $$\begin{align}2\sin\frac{5\theta}2\cos\left(-\frac{3\theta}2\right) &= 2\sin\frac{5\theta}2\cos\left(-\frac\theta2\right), \\ \sin\frac{5\theta}2\left(\cos\frac{3\theta}2 - \cos\frac\theta2\right) &= 0, 
>  \\ -2\sin\frac{5\theta}2\sin\theta\sin\frac\theta2 &= 0.\end{align}$$ The first factor gives solutions for $\theta$ of $-4\pi/5$, $-2\pi/5$, $0$, $2\pi/5$, and $4\pi/5$. The second factor gives rise to solutions $0$ and $\pi$, whilst the only value making the third factor zero is $\theta = 0$. The solution $\theta = 0$ appears in each of the above sets and so has multiplicity $3$.

Comment: Do you know that $\sin a + \sin b = 2 \sin \frac{a+b}{2} \cos \frac{ a-b} { 2} $? If no, can you prove it (maybe using the formulas that they listed)?

Comment: Thank you, after taking a look I see how the solution follows easily from the identity given by Calvin. Obviously the formula they gave and the one Calvin gave are fundamental compound angle identities and each derivable using similar principles. I was just confused as to how they used the identity they gave - I assume it is a mistake.

Comment: @amWhy.  I was typing and didn't look when posting. Meanwhile his appeared...

Comment: No problem, @imranfat. That's happened to me, too.   I deleted my former comment, and will delete this one shortly, after you have a chance to read it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They seem to have forgotten to mention that, from the first formula for the sine and the anlogous formula for $\sin(A-B)$, one deduces  a factorisation formula for a sum of sines, similar to the formula they mention for a sum of cosines:
$$\sin p+\sin q=2\sin\Bigl(\frac{p+q}2\Bigr)\cos\Bigl(\frac{p-q}2\Bigr).$$

*Edit*: I would personally have put it differently: observing that the arithmetic mean of the arguments of the sines is the same en each side of the initial equation is the same ($\frac{5\theta}2$), the equation can be rewritten as
\begin{alignat}{2}
&&\sin\Bigl(\frac{5\theta}2-\frac{3\theta}2\Bigr)+\sin\Bigl(\frac{5\theta}2+\frac{3\theta}2\Bigr)&=\sin\Bigl(\frac{5\theta}2-\frac{\theta}2\Bigr)+\sin\Bigl(\frac{5\theta}2+\frac{\theta}2\Bigr) \\
&\iff & 2\sin \frac{5\theta}2\cos\frac{3\theta}2 &= 2\sin \frac{5\theta}2\cos\frac{\theta}2 \\
&\iff &\sin \frac{5\theta}2=0\quad &\text{or}\quad\cos\frac{3\theta}2=\cos\frac{\theta}2 \\
&\iff& \frac{5\theta}2\equiv \frac{\pi}2\mod p\;&\text{ or } \;\frac{3\theta}2\equiv\pm\frac{\theta}2\mod 2\pi \\
&&\dots\dots\dots\dots\dots
\end{alignat}